# Get json from url and parsing information

Tags: android, json

I need get this two informations "matricula" and "nome" from a json from [this url](http://tcc-teste.aws.af.cm/api/get/aluno/1) but i dont know how to do this. I guess use [this class](https://gist.github.com/zvineyard/2012742) is a good option but i dont know how to use the method that get the json from url and i dont know how to work with array keys after get json. I'm sorry about i'm asking for you to do the whole work but is because i'm new on android dev and i'm really confused with jsonarray, jsonobjects etc..

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: nothing because i dont know how to handle jsonarray and jsonobject on java so that is the begining fot htis question.

Comment: try this Jackson library, it can decode your entity from InputStream by a few lines of code: http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonObject in like [Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in Java:

it store key with a value associated.

Example:

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
JsonObject obj1 = new JsonObject();
obj1.put("obj1_key1","obj1_value1");
obj1.put("obj1_key2","obj1_value2");
obj1.put("obj1_key3","obj1_value3");
obj.put("obj1",obj1);
```

JsonArray is like a [List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in Java:

it stores values with index from 0 to N.

Example:

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
JsonObject obj  = new JsonObject();
obj.put("xxx","yyy");
array.add(obj);
```

When you want to retrieve a json string remember that when array starts with `[]` you need to use JsonArray to parse it, when array starts with `{}` you need to use JsonObject

You can see an example [here](http://www.concretepage.com/java/example_json_java.php)

**YOUR JSON**

```
{"matricula":"201110460","nome":"Daniel de Faria Pedro"}
```

This is just a JsonObject because it has the classic "map" style key value association.
What you simple need to do is :

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://tcc-teste.aws.af.cm/api/get/aluno/1");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line = "", json = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
        json+=line;
    }                    
    JsonObject yourObject = new JsonObject(json);
    String matricula = yourObject.get("matricula");
    String nome = yourObject.get("nome");
    System.out.println(nome+" - "+matricula);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: sorry, but can you give me an example based on data structure from  json from url of my question? lets assume i already get data from url.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

Figuring that you get the information from a database with two columns, matricula and nome, and I imagine you would send an array so I would build the array with this code

```
 $json['test'][]=array( 'matricula'  => $row["matricula"], 'nome' =>$row["nome"])
```

Then I would parse that info like this assuming that you know how to get it:

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
 JSONArray test = object.getJSONArray("test");
 for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++){
     JSONObject c = test.getJSONObject(i);
     String matricula= c.getString("matricula");
     String nome = c.getString("nome");
     //do whatever you want with it
 }
```

Comment: What did you meant with this php array?

Comment: You can send more rows from your database at the same time. That's how you do the JSONArray and after that you can echo it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this example/tutorial I wrote on parsing `JSON` files using the native android `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` object or using the `Gson` library:

[Parsing JSON Files](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=746)